# Manage Chrome Browser Tabs and screen arrangement

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a use case in which I have to open an URL from Application A which is a SaaS web application. and during it's session Application A can request many URLs to open one by one but all should open in Same Browser Window Tab which was established on first click, in case Browser window is closed accidently next click will open it and subsequent URL request will open in same tab.

Second piece to this is opening on Screen 2 as i have dual monitor setup.

For use case one I was trying something by windows.open and naming that window it works one time next time open two new windows.

Please guide if this is possible? or if any other alternative framework which can help achieve this?

Comment: Javascript has no control how browser opens window/tabs. It can only control if browser should re-use previously opened tab/window (i.e. when link has `target="blah"` attribute with the same value)  or open a new one (`target="_blank"`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @vanowm, So if browser is open with a target/name and if we reuse same name again and again will it still use same tab or will ? is there a way to control Tabs ant way around other then JavaScript?